# Embed PDF in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, embed, pdf-viewer

I need to embed a PDF in an HTML document that can be viewed in IE8/9/10, firefox, and chrome on a .Net application.  I need to stay away from 3rd party libraries because we need to meet a release date and there isn't time to push new licenses through our legal department.  I've tried the following solutions and none of them worked for the reasons listed.  I don't think this should be hard to do, so any ideas are welcome.

```
<object src='MyUrl.pdf' />
```

Object tags didn't work because object tags in .Net require a class to be associated with them

```
<embed src='MyUrl.pdf' type='application/pdf' />
```

Embed tags don't seem to work in IE10.  Nothing gets displayed but a missing image icon

```
<iframe src='MyUrl.pdf' style="z-index: 1; zoom: 1" />
```

In IE10 , the z-index of the iframe cannot be controlled and the menus on the page drop down behind the frame.

As I mentioned, any help is appreciated.

Comment: '<iframe...' is probably the right answer.  Figure out why you're getting the missing image icon and you'll have the problem solved.  Does `MyUrl.pdf` exist if you type it in the address line of your browser?

Comment: @DanPichelman Sorry, the post was unclear, the iframe wasn't the missing image problem.  The ifram has the z-index problem.

Comment: Possibly of interest [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/291813/427192)

Comment: @DanPichelman Yeah, I looked at that post already.  That's where I got the idea for the embed tag.

Comment: @Pro..  No solution as of yet.  I basically rearranged the entire page to make sure the pdf never interferes with the surroundings.  Terrible answer, but it's where I'm at.

Comment: I have the same issue. Googled a lot and found that it is only IE bug with the z-index of pdf object. But still finding if I get anything.

Answer (score -1):

this works for me for most browsers.

I do have a z-index problem still in IE, since I have a fixed-position header.

```
<object data="myurl.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="600px" height="500px">
          <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
          <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
          <embed src="myurl.pdf"
                 type="application/pdf"
                 width="600px"
                 height="500px"
                 allowscriptaccess="always"
                 allowfullscreen="true"
                 wmode="transparent"
                 />
</object>
```

Comment: I have same issue and trying to resolve with that, but no effect at all.